# Is materialism a philosophy accepted by the majority in western societies?

Tags: materialism

I was in a philosophy class and the teacher mentioned some philosophical ideas and asked us to raise our hands if we agreed with a certain statement. The overwhelming majority agreed with **materialism** as in:

> "Materialism is a form of philosophical monism which holds that matter
>   is the fundamental substance in nature, and that all things, including
>   mental states and consciousness, are results of material
>   interactions."

Is there any reliable source that would allow me to say that:

"Materialism has taken hold in the West as the standard philosophy of the day."

Comment: There is no "philosophy accepted by the majority in western societies". You are confusing two meaning of materialism : one denotes a philosophical theory/worldview, while the other denotes a social attitude.

Comment: I am interested only in the theory/worldview and not at all in the social attitude.

Comment: I am just curious to know, if as in my classroom, most people think that the only thing that exists is matter and everything else is just an outcome of it.

Comment: [Rupert sheldrake](https://youtu.be/JKHUaNAxsTg) suggests the contrary; eg everyone knows someone who has "telepathic" dogs (knows when master is coming home) – a trivial example of somehing not explainable materialistically. IOW these questions get unnaturally high support because they are asked in a leading manner

Comment: It seems to be accepted by a majority of analytic philosophers, according to the [PhilPapers Poll](https://philpapers.org/surveys/results.pl), 56.5% "accept or lean toward physicalism".

Comment: @Conifold, very cool resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is materialism a philosophy accepted by the majority in western
>   societies?

If polling results are to be believed, **no**.

I base that on at least one good litmus test for materialism, which is whether one believes in gods or spirits of some kind--which materialism would disallow. We do have polling data on that issue, which I take from the "[Demographics of atheism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_atheism)" Wikipedia article, and which indicates that a clear majority of people do believe in gods or spirits throughout Europe and the Americas, as well as Australia/New Zealand:

- Europe: 51% believe in a god; 26% believe in spirit or life force (2010 poll).
- United States: 10% were atheists
- Mexico and South America: Percentages for atheism in single digits.
- Australia: Only 13% are "convinced atheists"

None of these regions have a majority atheist population, so none can have a majority materialism worldview.

> I was in a philosophy class and the teacher mentioned some
>   philosophical ideas and asked us to raise our hands if we agreed with
>   a certain statement. The overwhelming majority agreed with materialism

Keep in mind, it is possible that some of those that raised their hands misunderstood how far-reaching materialism is. It would have been interesting to ask them if they agreed with atheism, which is implied by materialism. Also keep in mind that a philosophy class is not a random cross-section of the population, but a group who have self selected to be there, and so they are likely not representative of the population of the West.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that the population of my classroom might not be at all representative. Thanks for the answer.